# Janela pop up bloquear Janela principal

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP porém utilizando algumas coisas em javascript no front... a verdade é que ainda não conheço muito de javascript, então queria saber o seguinte:

A situação é: Eu tenho um sistema de cadastros que funciona sobre a página principal. Porém há links para gerar novos cadastros ou editá-los que abrem em uma janela pop up para realizar o método POST. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, porém se o usuário minimizar a janela pop up, ela ficará escondida na barra de tarefas e não irá aparecer, mesmo que ele clique de novo. Isso faria com que usuarios menos experientes fiquem perdidos, além de tomar mais tempo...

O que eu queria saber é se há uma maneira de bloquear esse pop up na tela, forçando ele a ficar sobre a pagina principal, sem poder ser minimizado... não achei nada a esse respeito, então não sei se é possível. Mas acho que uma segunda alternativa, que já me atenderia bem, seria quando clicar sobre o link que gera o pop up, caso ele esteja minimizado, ele apareça novamente na frente do usuário... Porém não sei como fazer isso ^^'

Código que estou usando para gerar a pop up:

```js
function MM_openBrWindow(theUrl, winName, features) {
window.open(theUrl, winName, 'resizable=no, fullscreen=no, scrollbars=no, width=880, height=560, location=no, menubar=no, copyhistory=no, directories=no, status=no, toolbar=no');
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="MM_openBrWindow('nova_encomenda.php','Nova_Encomenda','')">
```

Comment: o que você precisa é uma janela modal, que ocupe a página até que seja fechada. Pode criar uma "na mão" ou usar algum framework que tenha isso pronto, como jquery, ou bootstrap

Comment: Acho que isso responde sua pergunta https://www.guj.com.br/t/janela-pop-up-para-impedir-navegacao/170539